# Encoding argument for cmd.exe

Tags: c#, character-encoding, cmd

I am using the System.Diagnostics.Process namespace to execute a command. The actual command is the full path to cmd.exe and the argument includes some specific Danish characters. Here is the full argument:

/c "echo Æ Ø Å æ ø å"

I am then trying to capture the output of the process. I have tried to send the StandardOutputEnconding to my encoding (1252) but it seems it does not help. I am suspecting that this might be related to input rather encoding as I am able to create a batch file with the above echo and run it with StandardOutputEncoding 1252.

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: Can you post a small code sample that shows this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly gets wrong, too?